# Should we cheat to change tags or just leave it how it is?

Tags: discussion

I used to go and add tags to peoples posts if they only used one tag (currently there are two questions tagged only "bearded dragons" which that tag has only 23 people following it, and I would go add it to "reptiles" and then another tag depending on their question). Recently ive noticed that stack exchange requires a 6 character change in the body of the post in order to edit it. I have also found out through experimentation that if you add a few spaces at the end you circumvent that without a noticeable change to the question and you can still add the tags.

So do you guys think this is a useful thing to do? Do you think we should circumvent the character limit just to change the tags or do you think it doesn't matter?

Comment: I'm fairly sure if you don't make _any_ changes to the body of the post but just change the tags, then it goes through as a tag edit (incl a suggested edit if less than 2k rep). I've done this on several SE sites. As soon as you touch the body of the post, that's where the 6 character limitation comes.

Comment: This is how it had worked for me too but recently ive been getting error messages for changing the body. Idk if it is my computer or something but it has only been recently that ive had to do this

Comment: Interesting. Maybe your browser is "modifying" the output when it displays it, or something like that...

Answer (score 6):

If you think a tag needs to be changed, change it.  As you get more rep you will have the option to directly edit tags.

> When you hover your mouse just to the right of the tags, you get a pop-up that says "Edit Tags"

I am not sure at what point this occurs I looked at [privileges](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and it did not jump out at me.  Privileges come at different levels for beta and promoted sites. I jumped around the other sites I have accounts at, was not able to define level for beta sites, but I think it should come between 1,000 and 2,000

In the meantime, if you think a change should be made to tags and you can make it happen, make the change.

There is a post [Should we be editing other users' posts for style?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593) that goes into more detail about when you should or should not edit.  Tags are important so they should always be addressed.